# Ubuntu still booting

Tags: boot

Okay, when I tried to install Ubuntu it showed up a code error so I uninstalled Ubuntu, but when the pc boots up it gives me an option if I want to start with windows or Ubuntu, and I already formatted my pc like 3 times and still giving the option to boot with Ubuntu and that annoys me, please help!

Comment: Did you reinstall windows like in this answer? http://askubuntu.com/a/143482/15939 Pay mind to the bit on removing grub from windows. It sounds like you've got GRUB left over on the MBR...

Answer (score 0):

You must restore the Windows boot sector to get rid of the start menu. Just search for "restore boot sector windows".  This is not a Windows forum, so explaning how you do it would, I think, not really fit here ...